# how to subtract a UILabel from another UILabel

Tags: uilabel, swift4, subtraction

I have a totalPoints UILabel and I want to subtract another label from it every time I click a button here is the code

```
totalPoints -= String(Cost)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't subtract one from the other, because UILabel deals with String. 
Use something like this:

var totalPoints: Int = 100

var cost: Int = 4

then do the math in the function, and update the UILabel accordingly:

myLabel.text = String(totalPoints)

Comment: Thank You! my only problem i'm getting is that now a warning pops up saying: result of operator '-' is unused